# React Nav Links Not Displaying Content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to learning React so I'm wondering if anyone can help me. I'm currently building a portfolio through React and I'm working on the Nav for this. I'm not getting any errors in the Console and when I click on each Link, it displays the Link I've clicked on in the URL but it won't show me any of my Content from each Link. Can anyone please help explain where I am going wrong?

App Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import Projects from './Projects.js'; 
import Contact from './Contact.js'; 
import About from './About.js'; 
import Skills from './Skills.js'; 
import Home from './App.js';
import './App.css';

function App() {
 return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />}></Route>
          <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />}></Route>
          <Route path="/skills" element={<Skills />}></Route>

      <div className="navigation">
        <div className="navigation-sub">
          <Link to="/" className="item">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/about" className="item">About</Link>
          <Link to="/contact" className="item">Contact</Link>
          <Link to="/projects" className="item">Projects</Link>
          <Link to="/skills" className="item">Skills</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
 );
}

export default App;
```

index Code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
 </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

About Code

```
import React from "react";

function About(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About Me</h1>
   </div>
  )
}

export default About;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: import Routes and wrap all Route with it

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#add-some-routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already rendering a `BrowserRouter` around `App`, so remove the extraneous `BrowserRouter` from `App`. The `Route` components are also missing being wrapped in a `Routes` component that handles path matching. It's a required component. You should have some console errors warning of invariant violations for the rendering of a router within another router and the routes not being wrapped directly by a `Routes` component.

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
        <Route path="/skills" element={<Skills />} />
      </Routes>
      <div className="navigation">
        <div className="navigation-sub">
          <Link to="/" className="item">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/about" className="item">About</Link>
          <Link to="/contact" className="item">Contact</Link>
          <Link to="/projects" className="item">Projects</Link>
          <Link to="/skills" className="item">Skills</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can collapse the empty tags in React also  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

Comment: @PatrickKelly True, but it doesn't hurt anything to render them empty.